# Add new user in OKD with htpasswd not working

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

i created users in OKD with below entry in ansible

```
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider'}]
openshift_master_htpasswd_users={'admin': 'xxx'}
```

As per my expectation if i create new user with htpasswd it should allow to login, but OKD is not accepting new users or i have to provide file name??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `filename` key in `openshift_master_identity_providers` has `default value`, such as `/etc/origin/master/htpasswd`.

For troubleshooting, first of all you should check the `htpasswd` file in your `master` node hosts. At the same time, you should also check your `/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml` whether or not the `indentityProvider` config is expected config.

If the above check list is no problem, you can test additional user for your OCP cluster as follows.

```
# htpasswd -b /etc/origin/master/htpasswd testuser testpasswd
```

And then, verify whether or not added account can authenticate.

I hope if help you. :^)